# Certificate CN as IPv6 address in square brackets

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

Can we generate a certificate with IPv6 addresss in square brackets in CN ?

For eg. : CN = [2001:100:1000:1000:20c:29ff:fe88:88ab]

Answer (score 1):

IP addresses in CN will not be checked, you have to use subjectAltName Extension to store IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.

Comment: commonName (CN) is a string type and you can store anything inside it, but it will not verify an IP address, even with brackets, because it expects a hostname. subjectAltName can have several types, among them GEN_DNS for hostname and GEN_IP for IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. GEN_IP are stored as binary in the certificate. This means, that it depends on the tool you use to create the certificate if brackets are needed or not.

Answer (score 1):

IP addresses do not get stored as a CN, they have their own specific IP place they belong.  See the example at https://[2606:4700:4700::1111]/

Here's how to make the CSR:-

```
openssl req -new -sha256 -nodes -out d.ip6only.com.csr -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout d.ip6only.com.key -config <(echo -e "[req]\ndefault_bits = 2048\nprompt = no\ndefault_md = sha256\nreq_extensions = req_ext\ndistinguished_name = dn\n\n[ dn ]\nC=US\nST=Texas\nL=Houston\nO=Example\nOU=Example\nemailAddress=abuse@Example\n\n[ req_ext ]\nsubjectAltName = @alt_names\n\n[ alt_names ]\nIP.1 = 2a22:3071:1:2:2d00::3\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure what Mr. Ullrich means by "*...but it* [SAN] *will not verify an IP address...*", as the SAN can contain any type of OID `otherName:*`, as well as `dirName:*`, `IP.*`, `DNS.*`, and `email.*`.

If a SAN contains `IP.1 = 192.168.1.1` and `DNS.1 = your.ddns.com`, navigating to either will verify the IP or DNS as a valid.

Comment: You misunderstood Steffen Ullrich, "it" refers to the CN, not SAN.

Comment: Either way, a CN can be an IP address and the cert will verify that IP address as valid when navigated to.  Anyone can verify this, as this has been how SSL certs have worked since I began using them almost a decade ago.  It may be that WAN certs cannot contain IPs in the CN, but LAN certs can.
How does one believe a router's WebAdmin page is secured, as it's not by a hostname, but by the IP address if SANs were not utilized.  For example, if a user installs uHTTPd on OpenWrt, it comes with a script baked into uHTTPd's config, of  which creates an SSL cert w/ LuCI's IP address as the CN.